# How to setup email verification with Django-Verify-Email

Tags: django

I get an invalid link in the email every time i register a new user with this package

here is my code

```
def signup(request, form_class, template_name, success_message, redirect_url):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(redirect_url)
    form = form_class()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_verification_email(request, form)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, success_message)
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, f'Error creating account. Please check the form.')
            return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)



def student_signup(request):
    return signup(
        request,
        StudentRegistrationForm,
        'user/student/signup.html',
        'Student account created successfully.',
        'user:signin'
    )
```

I am using this django package

https://github.com/foo290/Django-Verify-Email

This is the send_verification_email  from the package

Addcording to the documentation, the defaults setting should work fine

Comment: Provide your `send_verification_email ` method code.

Comment: i am using a pypi package called Django-Verify-Email, i can't past the method in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the github [docs](https://github.com/foo290/Django-Verify-Email#step-4--) it mentions you do not have to call form.save() as this is handled by the send_verification_email function. See also this [issue](https://github.com/foo290/Django-Verify-Email/issues/53) which seems to have a similar problem solved by removing form.save()